# Eliminate inclusion of X11 libs in initrd

Tags: debian, initrd, qnap

I'm running Debian Bookworm on a TS412 (QNAP); it stores the kernel & initrd in flash. It has a total of 16MB of flash. So even after tweaking with the MD partitions the best I can get is a 12MB initrd . I'm using xz compression. But even so, the initial initrd was 12.5MB. I know the common fix is to reduce modules, but they are not the real issue.

```
2984    .../usr/lib/modules
6036    .../usr/share
18824   .../usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi
```

Looking in arm-linux-gnueabi it had stuff like libX11... This machine does not even have a console (even getting a serial line is difficult) it certainly does not need "X".

So I removed lots of packages totally (apt-get remove ...) in fact rather more than I should really. But the result was a much smaller initrd (about 5MB IIRC) which boots and runs just fine.

Problem is, if I ssh onto the box and run say emacs(1) it'd be nice to project the GUI version back to my normal desktop (which has lots of memory and big displays, etc.) but this would require installing the X client libraries on the TS412.

Now I don't see why just because I have the package with the X client libraries installed, that a copy needs to be kept on initrd, they aren't needed during boot. Is there a way to limit other stuff from getting onto initrd, not just modules (which are not the culprit)

I've already tried document searches for guides to limit initrd.

Comment: it would seem like a mistake that these were included in the initrd to begin with, indeed.

Comment: Instead of `ssh -X my-box emacs` you can mount part of the  box' FS with sshfs and use emacs on your main machine.

Comment: I can't help but wonder, are you using some kind of weird variant of debian that the initramfs is being used as the real root?

Comment: @TomYan that's not the case. I discovered I also had X11 libraries pulled in one Debian's initramfs but not an other, and checked why, hence my answer. But if something is not on the actually installation (the actual / ) it can't be pulled in initramfs. So when OP removed some key packages, this triggered a rebuild of initramfs (or it was triggered manually), *without* the extra cruft which didn't exist anymore.

Comment: So "projecting emacs" was just an example where I'd like to install stuff on QNAP (as a convenience) but not have it appear on initrc.

I'm sure the initrd is NOT ending up as /(root) because I have a script installed in /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/  which chooses root dynamically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There could be a binary intended to display graphical information during boot that would pull libraries it depends upon in the *initramfs* file.

One such binary available on most architectures, including `armel` is the `label.so` plugin provided by [`plymouth-label`](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/plymouth-label) as a plugin for [Plymouth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plymouth_(software)) in order to have a graphical display with text during boot. This plugin depends on various X11 libraries and is used to render *text*. When this plugin is added to the *initramfs* all the libraries it depends upon are also added so it can be used in the boot phase. This is advertised by the package's dependencies: `plymouth-label` depends on [`libcairo2`](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/libcairo2) which itself depends on various X11 library packages including [`libx11-6`](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/libx11-6) [providing the library `libX11.so.6`](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/armel/libx11-6/filelist).

The initramfs hook adding `label.so` would be [`/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/plymouth/-/blob/debian/22.02.122-3/debian/local/plymouth.hook#L33):

> ```bash
> PLUGIN_PATH="$(plymouth --get-splash-plugin-path)"
>
> case "${THEME_NAME}" in
>   text|details|tribar)
>       PLUGINS="text.so details.so"
>       ;;
>   *)
>       PLUGINS="text.so details.so label.so"
>       ;;
> esac
>
> [...]
>
> for PLUGIN in ${PLUGINS}
> do
>   if [ -f ${PLUGIN_PATH}/${PLUGIN} ]
>   then
>       copy_exec ${PLUGIN_PATH}/${PLUGIN}
>   else
> [...]
> ```

`copy_exec` is a shell function (provided by `initramfs-tools-core`) that will pull the dependencies whenever needed in addition to copying the binary, relying on `ldd` to discover what's needed.

so it appears it would be pulled only when a non-text setting is used in Plymouth... in order to display text.

As a QNAP's main purpose is not video, having *plymouth* installed and especially this plugin should be avoided, avoiding X11 libraries to be pulled in the *initramfs* file.

I fail to see any other cause for this behavior. There could be an other similar package causing this behavior for similar reasons.

Comment: I missed the "So I removed lots of packages totally". But searching in `/var/log/apt/*` should still be able to tell if this triggered the removal of `plymouth-label`.

Comment: $ ls /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks                                                                              
dmsetup                fuse         kmod     plymouth  thermal                    
flash_kernel_set_root  keymap       mdadm    qcontrol  udev                       
fsck                   klibc-utils  ntfs_3g  resume    zz-busybox

So I do have plymouth (which I guess addresses the initial question) . I see I also have ntfs_3g and I have not need any Microsoft formats (certainly not to boot) also mdadm and dmsetup and I boot from simple partitions (I do use RAID, but later)

Comment: I guess it would be useful to understand the "general principal" ... Given I find "X" (;- ) ) on initrd, how do I work back to the cause (akin to apt-rdepends) 

$ apt-rdepends plymouth | wc                 
....    312     929    7945

BTW does not include sting X11

Comment: You already removed plymouth-label by your previous actions. The only place left is the logs. So as I wrote in my first answer's comment, you have to check for the word plymouth-label in /var/log/apt (most logs are compressed by the way: zcat or zgrep...)

Comment: To be clear: installing X11 on the server won't add it in initramfs. Only very special packages meant for running *at boot* with *graphics* would do this. The only one I found is plymouth-label. If your package is not related to booting, it won't do it. If your package (related to booting) is not related to display, it won't do it. If it does both, you might consider reading its description and checking its dependencies. plymouth (alone) won't do it either. While it's not written, that's the probable reason plymouth-label was packaged separately. For its cumbersome dependencies.

Comment: (1st remember I admitted to removing "too much")

1: I just did (before you most recent comments) sudo apt-get remove plymouth (it did an update-initramfs)
2: Looking back in (bash) history, I see I did:  apt remove xserver-common
   apt remove libx11-6 libxdmcp6 libglib2.0-0
3: Looking in /var/log/apt/history.log , I see a line starting Remove: emacs:armel (1:28.2+1-15), libjaxb-java:armel (2.3.0.1-10.1),  (the line is 16294 character long  ...so lots of stuff)  includes plymouth-label:armel (22.02.122-3),

You say "The only one I found" ... could you show your workings?

Answer (score 1):

Having followed the logic of @A.B useful reply. I knocked up a quick & dirty pair of scripts to help in following back up the depends tree.
(the A.B. answer remains the answer to the specific question)

```
graeme@qnap412u:/tmp/myinitrd$ xzcat /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-13-marvell  | cpio -i
34382 blocks

graeme@qnap412u:/tmp/myinitrd$ ~/bin/genxrefs.sh /tmp/myinitrd/  > /tmp/refs
Doing /tmp/myinitrd/usr/lib/klibc-tUxlTFMpGlp_BpS5UnpMpyc8b3g.so
    not a dynamic executable
Doing /tmp/myinitrd/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/ld-linux.so.3
Doing /tmp/myinitrd/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libkmod.so.2.4.0
..elided..

graeme@qnap412u:/tmp/myinitrd$ ~/bin/whoneeds.awk  libudev /tmp/refs 
libudev.so.1 is used by /tmp/myinitrd/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libdevmapper.so.1.02.1

graeme@qnap412u:/tmp/myinitrd$ ~/bin/whoneeds.awk devmapper  /tmp/refs 
graeme@qnap412u:/tmp/myinitrd$ ~/bin/whoneeds.awk libatomic  /tmp/refs 
libatomic.so.1 is used by /tmp/myinitrd/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libkmod.so.2.4.0
libatomic.so.1 is used by /tmp/myinitrd/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libcrypto.so.3


graeme@qnap412u:/tmp/myinitrd$ cat ~/bin/genxrefs.sh
#! /bin/bash -ue

# This will fail if any names uses spaces or commas (at a pinch, we could use TAB)

INITDIR=$1

objs=$(find ${INITDIR} -type f -name '*.so.*' -o -path '*.so')

# This is going to mess up if anybody uses spaces in pathnames
for obj in ${objs}
do
    echo "Doing ${obj}" >&2
    ldd ${obj} | while read line
    do
    requires=${line%% =>*}
    requires=${requires%% *} # 1st word
    requires=$(basename ${requires})
    
    provided=${line#*=>}

    # Ugly , we use commas because, for example quoted strings are too hard in awk(1)
    
    echo "${obj},${requires},${provided}"
    done  
done
graeme@qnap412u:/tmp/myinitrd$ cat ~/bin/whoneeds.awk
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    # NB this version of awk does not appear to understand FPAT
    FS=","

    STRING=ARGV[1]
    ARGV[1]=""
}

{ if ( index($2, STRING) > 0 )
    print $2 " is used by " $1 }
```

Comment: On my original initrd:

graeme@qnap412u:/tmp/myinitrd$ ~/bin/whoneeds.awk X11  /tmp/refs 
libX11.so.6 is used by /home/graeme/initrd1/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libcairo.so.2.11600.0
libX11.so.6 is used by /home/graeme/initrd1/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libXext.so.6.4.0
libX11.so.6 is used by /home/graeme/initrd1/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0.4600.2
libX11.so.6 is used by /home/graeme/initrd1/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libXrender.so.1.3.0
libX11.so.6 is used by /home/graeme/initrd1/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/plymouth/label.so